# Create json api for mobile application using php mysql

Tags: php, json

Hello I need to create a json encode api for the code which i am building

Currently my project have 3 tables item table,payment table and sms table

item table contains the details of my project and the item table is linked to payment and sms table

i am listing the json form which i want to make

```
{ 

"Data": { 

"Projects": [{ 
"id": "10023", 
"Info": "Arabic project info ", 
"paymentMethods": { 
"Bank": [{ 
"accname": "Zakat Acc", 
"accnameEn": "حساب الزكــــــاة", 
"country": "UAE", 
"acc": "0034430430012"
}, { 
"accname": "Zakat Acc", 
"accnameEn": "حساب الزكــــــاة",
"country": "UAE", 
"acc": "00344304332412"
}], 
"SMS": [{ 
"operatorEn": "etisalat", 
"shortcode": "4236", 
"operator": "إتصالات"
}, { 
"operatorEn": "etisalat", 
"shortcode": "4346", 
"operator": "إتصالات"
}], 
"CC": {
"-URL": 
"http://www.sharjahcharuty.org/donations/" 
} 
} 
}, { 
"id": "10026", 
"Info": "Arabic project info ", 
"InfoEn": "project info in english", 
"paymentMethods": { 
"Bank": [{ 
"accname": "Zakat Acc", 
"accnameEn": "حساب الزكــــــاة", 
"country": "UAE", 
"acc": "0034430430012"
}, { 
"accname": "Zakat Acc", 
"accnameEn": "حساب الزكــــــاة", 
"country": "UAE", 
"acc": "00344304332412"
}], 
"SMS": [{ 
"operatorEn": "etisalat", 
"shortcode": "4236", 
"operator": "إتصالات"
}, { 
"operatorEn": "etisalat", 
"shortcode": "4346", 
"operator": "إتصالات"
}], 
"CC": { 
"-URL": "http://www.sharjha.org/donations/" 
} 
} 
}] 
}
}
```

I have created php code for the system
But this code i have create using brackets and seperated by queries but this system not giving the result what i expected

```
echo $string='{"Data":{';


//echo $string='"Projects":';
$sql2 = "SELECT *  FROM wg_items where cat_id=6007;";
$query = $this->db->query($sql2);
echo $string='"Projects":';
echo $string='[';
$intcount=0;
$scateg="";
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($query->result() as $row){

//$jsonrows[]=array("id"=>$row->cat_id,"name"=>$row->item_name);
echo $string='{';
echo $string = 'id:'.$row->item_id;
echo $string=',';
echo $string = 'name:'.$row->item_name;
echo $string=',';
//-------------------------------------------------------------//
$hasComma = false;
echo $string='"paymentmethods":';
echo $string='"Bank":[';
$sql2 = "SELECT  * FROM paymentmethods where cid=587 ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql2);
foreach ($query->result() as $row){
       echo '{';
       echo $string = 'accname:'.$row->acc.',' ;
       echo $string = 'country:'.$row->IBAN.',' ;
       echo $string = 'Iban:'.$row->Bankname.',' ;
       echo $string = 'Bankname:'.$row->Bankname.',' ;
       echo $string = '},';  
}  
echo $string = '],';

echo $string='"SMS":[';
$sql3 = "SELECT  * FROM sms where cid=537 ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql3);
$hasComma = false;
foreach ($query->result() as $rows){
    echo '{';

    echo  'Operator:'.$rows->operator.',' ;
    echo  'shortcode:'.$rows->shortcode.',';
    echo  'keyword:'.$rows->keyword.',';
    echo  'price:'.$rows->price;


     echo $string = '},';  
     if($hasComma = TRUE)
     {

     }
     $hasComma = TRUE;
} 
echo $string = '}],';

echo $string='"CC":{';

echo $string3='"-URL:"';
 echo $string3='"HTTP:SHARJAHCHARTITY.COM"';
 ECHO '}}}';
 echo ',';
}
echo ']}}}';
```

Comment: Dont build JSON Strings manually. Create objects and arrays in the form you want the data and then use `json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not suppose to append strings to create a json string.
Create an array which holds the data and wrap it with **json_encode()** function
For ex:

```
<?php

$array_data=[];

$array_data['firstname']="Rafique";
$array_data['lastname']="Mohammed";
$array_data['email']="plus.arr@gmail.com";

// or any data which you want in json

$json_output=json_encode($array_data);

echo $json_output;
```

OUTPUT :

```
{"firstname":"Rafique","lastname":"Mohammed","email":"plus.arr@gmail.com"}
```

**UPDATE 2 :**

In your case

```
<?php

//.. your code

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach ($query->result() as $row){

$jsonrows=array("id"=>$row->item_id,"name"=>$row->item_name);


$jsonrows["paymentmethods"]=array("Bank"=>[]);

$sql2 = "SELECT  * FROM paymentmethods where cid=587 ";
$query = $this->db->query($sql2);

foreach ($query->result() as $row){
//convert bank as array
      $jsonrows["paymentmethods"]["Bank"][] = array(
         "accname"=>$row->acc,
         "country"=>$row->IBAN,
         "Iban"=>$row->Bankname,
         "Bankname"=>$row->Bankname );

}  

//DO IT FOR REST OF THE CODE
```

Comment: thank you so much but for bank paymentmethods":{"Bank":{"accname":"0506796049","country":"DE690240002520511717801","Iban":"ARABIC BANK NAME","Bankname":"ARABIC BANK NAME"} it is comming like this what i need is  "Bank": [{ 
"accname": "Zakat Acc", 
"accnameEn": "حساب الزكــــــاة", 
"country": "UAE", 
"acc": "0034430430012"
}, { 
"accname": "Zakat Acc", 
"accnameEn": "حساب الزكــــــاة", 
"country": "UAE", 
"acc": "00344304332412"
}]

Comment: you want array for the "Bank"=[] or you want it as object "Bank"={} ??

Comment: thank you for your reply..i want it as "Bank": [{ }]

Comment: If you want "Bank" as array then simply convert it as array! Check my updated anwser

Comment: thank you :)can you please tel me how to do that for sms also :)

Comment: @riz Figure it out yourself brother. so that's the way you can learn how to do it yourself next time ;-) but as a hint, Use the same $jsonrows array for the SMS too. for ex: $jsonrows['sms']=array(); and within the loop do it same as bank. for ex: $jsonrows['sms'][]=array("Operator"=>$rows->operator,//rest of the data)